# How to recover lost partition from parted - NixOs and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I attempted to install NixOs on a machine that already had an Ubuntu install on it. Following the installation guide here: https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/, I followed steps 2.1.1, 2.2.2, and then the mkswap 2.2.3 direction. After I did so, I realized that it erased the partition for the Ubuntu install, but it seems to still be installed on the computer. How might I recover the Ubuntu installation, if at all possible?

Comment: Reinstall. What you think "still be installed on the computer" is only a now non-working efi entry. You deleted the partition, it's gone.

Comment: If you stopped before formatting the new partitions, just reset the partition sizes to what they were -- the old filesystem/data should still be there.